# Why do my query values and number of fields not match?

Tags: vb.net

I keep running this code and getting the error that the number of query's and fields do not match, why would this be?

```
    Sub StoreInDB()
    Try
        ConnectionString.close()
         Dim arrayname() As String = import.FileNames
        For Each Trackname As String In arrayname
            Using sql As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert into tbplaylist (path, AlbumName)values('" & Replace(Trackname, "'", "''", albumname.ToString) & "')", ConnectionString.open)
                If import.FileName = Nothing Then
                Else
                    For Each track As String In import.FileNames
                    Next
                End If
                sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ConnectionString.close()
            End Using
            ConnectionString.close()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    ConnectionString.close()
    End Try
    ConnectionString.close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Because you try to insert into two columns (`path`, `AlbumName`), but only supply one value (`Replace(Trackname, "'", "''", albumname.ToString)`).  I guess you misplaced the ending paranthesis. You should really parameterize your query.

Comment: Hi, thanks! How would I write this query out for it to work? If you wouldn't mind explaining I would appreciate that

Comment: Could you please adjust your tags? This is for sure not VBA

Comment: Sorry! I've changed this now

Comment: It's not SQL either. What language is it? [Edit] to tag that.

Comment: Apologies, I'm abit confused as you can see haha, I've changed this

Comment: You should have been able to see what the issue was simply based on the syntax highlighting but, failing that, if you'd bothered to look at the actual SQL code then you'd have seen the issue. You should read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html). Even if you had used the `String.Format` option then you'd have been less likely to make this mistake because your code would have been more easily readable. Parameters are a better option yet, for several reasons.

Comment: Okay, Sorry for this! I'm relatively new to this and was just wondering where I was going wrong, I'll make sure to read what you linked so I can rectify it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert into statement has two columns path and albumname
`insert into tbplaylist (path, AlbumName)`

But you have put only one value in values part.

Please try this:

```
Using sql As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert into tbplaylist (path, AlbumName)values('" & Replace(Trackname, "'", "''") & "','" & albumname.ToString & "')", ConnectionString.open)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, do you know how I would structure the values part to insert both?

Comment: Hi, I've tried this but it returns the same error

Comment: Sorry. I have already corrected my mistake. missed two single quoted around comma.